# How do I close the User Preferences window when it is not opened by the window manager?

Tags: customization

I am running FreeBSD 10.2 64 bit with fvwm-crystal. In all other cases, just starting a program from an xterm opens a window with buttons. Blender does not open in a window with buttons, which in itself is not a problem. However, when I try to set user preferences, the new window does not have buttons, and I can not close the User Preferences window. I tried "dbus-launch blender" but no difference. I do not see any configuration options for recompiling blender that might make any difference. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to access blender's preferences without encountering this issue? Or how to get the wm to put buttons on blender?

Comment: Do you get the title bar of the window so you can drag it around? Blender should get a normal window with standard close/resize widgets the same as any other program, the same when a new window is created for preferences. I use xfce and can use Alt-F4 to close a window (that's a window manager setting), also right clicking on the title bar of the window gives a menu with a close option. This would be window manager related, you would do better trying fvwm support options, or maybe emailing the freebsd-questions list or [forums.freebsd.org](http://forums.freebsd.org)

Comment: @gandalf3 I would certainly be satisfied with being able to access user preferences without encountering this issue. Although I am curious about why fvwm-crystal is not putting buttons on blender, I sense that that question may be difficult to answer.

Comment: @sambler There is no title bar from the window manager. The top of the window contains the names of the sections: Interface, Editing, etc. Using fvwm-crystal's command to close the User Preference window causes Blender to quit. I will certainly look to freebsd or fvwm lists for help if there is no solution within Blender.

Comment: I hadn't looked at the [cli options](https://www.blender.org/manual/advanced/command_line.html#window-options) for a while - blender has `-w` to force opening with window borders (default) and `-W` to force without window borders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the preferences inside the existing blender window by setting the [*editor type*](https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/window_system/introduction.html) in the header of any existing *[area](https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/window_system/arranging_areas.html)*:

[image]

As for why blender isn't getting a titlebar from the wm, I have no idea. It works fine for me here on openbox.